# How can I retrieve the number of rows clicked?

Tags: sapui5

I create this table:

```
tableResult.bindAggregation("items", "/items", new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
            cells: tableResult.getModel().getProperty("/cols").map(function (colname) {
                return new sap.m.Label({ text: "{" + colname + "}" });
            }),
            type:"Navigation",
            press:"handleRowPress"
        }));
        tableResult.setProperty("visible",true);
```

In the function `handleRowPress`, how can I retrieve the number of the rows (first, second,...n'th) clicked?

Comment: Have you checked the `sap.m.Table` method `indexOfItem()` method (which is borrowed from class `sap.m.ListBase`) already? https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/sdk/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListBase.html#indexOfItem

Comment: Excuse me, i rewrite my problem:
I have handleRowPress function

`handleRowPress : function(evt){
  evt.......
  
 }`

How i can retireve the number of selected item from "evt"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better, UI5 provided solution would be :

```
handleRowPress : function(oEvent){
    var selectedRowNum = oEvent.getSource().indexOfItem(oEvent.getParameter("listItem"));
    console.log(selectedRowNum);
}
```

NB: Retrieving the index from a generated ID is generally a bad idea, specially when considering sorting/filtering etc ;-)

Comment: ok it work, but why every time I click on item i have this error?

`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function sap-ui-core.js:122`

Comment: I have no idea without looking at your code... have a look at this working example: http://jsbin.com/vikoc/1/edit?js,console,output

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution!

```
handleRowPress : function(evt){
        var path=evt.getParameter("listItem");
        var sId=path.sId;
        var selectedRowNum = sId.substr(sId.lastIndexOf("-") + 1);
        console.log(selectedRowNum);

    }
```